# Why do file transfers take a long time to stop?

Tags: macos, filesystem, file, file-transfer

I encounter this problem a lot, and I've also had it on Windows.

It doesn't matter if it's over a network, or locally on a hard drive, but file transfers never stop when I click the stop button. They always take 20-30+ seconds to stop.

I have encountered this issue across multiple Macs, and even on my old Windows PCs I used to use.

Is there something inherent about file transfers that cause this massive delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With file transfers, both copy and move, cancelling the operation tries to not interrupt the current file being transferred. When interrupting a file transfer, Finder finishes the current file, so that you are not left with two corrupt half-files in both locations. This means you can continue the operation later, or move the files back (if it's a move), if you so wish.

Comment: I see. Would it not be a good idea to have two buttons, pause and stop, so that the buttons do what they say they do? Could the stop button not actually stop the transfer and then remove the half finished file afterwards? That must be possible.  Anywho, thank you for your answer, much appreciated.

Comment: @thephpdev Yes! Finder doesn't support this, but you can use [CopyQueue](http://www.curiosoftware.com/copyqueue/index.html). The problem with showing the user that the file operation has finished is that the user may then attempt to interact with the files that are still undergoing an operation or may eject the removable media.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the following problem on and off for a while, and here is how I solved it.

I believe after researching on this topic for a long time and running a few tests on a couple of machines, that when the Finder is slow to duplicate / move / delete a file has to do with the graphics cars and background tasks which are difficult to troubleshoot.

I am not claiming that this solution is 100% efficient, and I am certainly not an expert, but it worked exceptionally well for me, and has the advantage of being quite fast and simple, so I wanted to share it.

**The process I followed made these tasks much faster *immediately*, and was actually a simple process to follow compared to other, more complex solutions I have seen online:**

-if you're running **Time Machine**, eject it for a moment, you can plug it back after trying these steps - Time Machine will often run in the background without necessarily being obvious, but it consumes RAM and probably also the same resources that are necessary to deal with files;

[image]

-if you have **peripherals** plugged in the computer, unplug them all except for the ones that are required to operate basic tasks (keyboard, mouse...). This is also true for memory cards and others more discreet peripherals (bluetooth, etc);

[image]

-if there are lots of **icons on the desktop** of your computer, clean it and reduce the amount of icons to a bare minimum. [This is an important step](http://lifehacker.com/5893054/an-overly-cluttered-desktop-can-seriously-slow-down-your-mac--clean-it-up-for-a-noticeable-speed-boost), as I believe that having images (JPEGs, etc) and sometimes even folders on the desktop sucks a lot of power from the machine, as it is constantly using the graphics card and RAM to display thumbnails;

[image]

-if there are **folders that contain more than 1000 elements on your machine**, break this number into smaller numbers by creating dated folders or categorizing. I believe that running extensive file trees also consumes a lot of efficiency for the machine as it constantly catalogs files in the background;

[image]

-after saving your work or documents or your tabs, **quit all the applications you are not using**, and try to **only ever use under 4-5 applications at the same time** while always **quitting the ones you are not currently using**;

[image]

-if you have many tabs of Safari (or another browser) open at the same time, or a few tabs that are extensive in their use of JavaScript or Flash, **reduce the number of tabs to be under 20**. This is another very important step to increase the computer's performance, as frequent background tasks on websites such as Facebook, Twitter, etc can load the computer's performance drastically;

[image]

-**give your hard-drive some breathing space**. If you're running RAM-greedy apps such as Safari or Firefox with lots of tabs open or creative applications (image editing, 3D, etc) on very little free HD space, it's also without a doubt one reason why the computer has trouble multitasking. It's time to use a file)mapping application, and back-up externally the files that are encumbering the hard drive and that you use the least often;

[image]

-once all these steps have been followed, **repair permissions on the hard drive** of your machine **and restart**.

[image]

Things should go much better after these steps have been followed.

Good luck, and if you have any comments, feel free to share them below.

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not answer the question. It may be good advice for how to speed up a computer in general, but it does not answer the question of why a file copy does not stop immediately, beyond a vague allusion to "graphics cars and background tasks". If you were a new contributor, I'd let it go, but you have 3000+ reputation, so I expect you understand this. Downvoting.

Comment: That’s a bit rude and ignorant. I was indeed a new contributor 4 years ago, and gained my rep after I posted this through one single question. This answer required effort and time when I was a newbie. Sorry if you don’t like it and sorry for the typo in “graphics card”. Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: I apologise for coming across as rude. That wasn't what I intended. I thought it was better to explain myself than to be a downvote out of the blue, and better to vote than not to vote. Voting is part of the magic here. Congratulations on your excellent USB-C question.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I appreciate. I don’t think voting holds as much of a holy meaning as you think for either questions or the act of voting - otherwise popular political candidates would also magically happen to be the best ones at their jobs. Voting is done by people and can create a snowball effect giving more exposure to some Qs less deserving. My answer here covers a lot of ground, and has worked for me and friends. A bad answer would be an answer in bad English or badly put together. This one doesn’t deserve a downvote. If nothing in it solves your issue I would be surprised.